# PgfPlots Histogram: wrong density on y-Axis

Tags: pgfplots, statistics, histogram

I want to make a pgfplots histogram to visualize the jitter of a 260 MHz clock signal. I want to use the probability density on the y-Axis. Yet, when I try this, the y-Axis does not display the percentage, nor the number of bin elements.

[image: resulting plot]

Here is the code with a few example values:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents*}{clk260period.csv}
3.85307942015e-09
3.82802980405e-09
3.84871995265e-09
3.85734095869e-09
3.84800331273e-09
3.83545067472e-09
3.87078519524e-09
3.84597431986e-09
3.82591047015e-09
3.86182286686e-09
3.84048879946e-09
3.83720978908e-09
3.84097879924e-09
3.85360457335e-09
3.83966296654e-09
3.85547204479e-09
3.86168154569e-09
3.83705593078e-09
3.83339948811e-09
3.8636352965e-09
3.83143047443e-09
3.83459532403e-09
3.85677759304e-09
3.85449617442e-09
3.83720978908e-09
3.8672467332e-09
3.84035929045e-09
3.84426447529e-09
3.83784788498e-09
3.85955170352e-09
3.82699015554e-09
3.83593005479e-09
3.86832747192e-09
3.84816852032e-09
3.83753966837e-09
3.86169462912e-09
3.85231149401e-09
3.83668960449e-09
3.83811557696e-09
3.85831377285e-09
3.81494262473e-09
3.84871995265e-09
3.86101865609e-09
3.84432561534e-09
3.83704905172e-09
3.86918681823e-09
3.8509406669e-09
3.8209441231e-09
3.86182286686e-09
3.84630360665e-09
3.83139498189e-09
3.84954137557e-09
3.85072248095e-09
3.83967577434e-09
3.84613397217e-09
3.8710093959e-09
3.8430981029e-09
3.82324510938e-09
3.86516754338e-09
3.84512733977e-09
3.8177953491e-09
3.86233465957e-09
3.85352399329e-09
3.84366402504e-09
3.84496994696e-09
3.8573419675e-09
3.85074404558e-09
3.83685953589e-09
3.85612838163e-09
3.82527488571e-09
3.83149321839e-09
3.86596007496e-09
3.85390991637e-09
3.8279072429e-09
3.86629225025e-09
3.85669588812e-09
3.83772450636e-09
3.83595280452e-09
3.85000075e-09
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar,ymin=0]
            \addplot +[hist={bins=40,density}] table [y index=0] {clk260period.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `density` key, according to pgfplots manual, renormalizes the y-values, making the total area of the histogram equal to 1

Comment: So how would I approach this to get the y axis to display the probability of a measurement value falling into each bin without changing the values displayed at the x-Axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The y values of the histogram are, by default, the counts in each bin. The `density` key renormalizes them in a way that the total area of the histogram is 1. I don't know any "automatic" way to have the fractions as y values, but you can apply an `y filter` to divide the counts by the total number of values (in the case of your example 79). Therefore, the following code should do what you ask for:

```
\addplot +[hist={bins=40}, y filter/.expression={y/79}] table [y index=0] {clk260period.csv};
```

I don't know how to avoid hardcoding `79`, that is the total number of values.

Comment: This works for me. I have only three sets of data, so it isn't too much of a hassle. Thanks.