# Histogram from list of number

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot a histogram, preferably in tikz, that draws the distribution from a list of numbers, e.g. 124,235,46,399,...

I have found many examples that show how to draw a histogram from a table of values, but none that would draw a plot from a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a list into a table with `\pgfplotstableread`, for example:

```
\pgfplotstableread{124,235,46,399,150,124,45\\}\data
```

which stores the list in `\data`.

Now this data is read as a row, and for a histogram `pgfplots` expects the data in a column. Therefore you can transpose the table:

```
\pgfplotstabletranspose{\coldata}{\data}
```

Now you can plot it following one of the examples you find about plotting from a table.

Below an MWE with a frequency plot and a density plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{table/col sep = comma,table/row sep=\\}
\pgfplotstableread{124,235,46,399,150,124,45\\}\data
\pgfplotstabletranspose{\coldata}{\data}
% below only for density plot, example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328855/
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\coldata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, ymin=0, ytick distance=1]
\addplot +[
    hist={bins=4, data min=0},
] table {\coldata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, ymin=0, ymax=1]
\addplot +[
    hist={bins=4, data min=0},
    y filter/.expression={y/\N},
] table {\coldata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]